# How to replace some words with few word in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string in sql like these:

```
AB-FirstHalf(x)
AB-SecondHalf(y)

AB-FirstHalf(a)
AB-SecondHalf(b)
```

where x,y,a,b are the DivisionNames (which I cannot write here)

What I want is to show only FH in case if there is FirstHalf in the string and show SH if there is SecondHalf in the string.

For example:

```
AB-FirstHalf(x)       // should show FH
AB-SecondHalf(y)      // should show SH

AB-FirstHalf(a)       // should show FH
AB-SecondHalf(b)      // should show SH
```

where FH and SH are short names for First Half and Second Half respectively.

I am using **Replace** method in sql but it's not working as I expect.

**I am using MS-SQL version 14**

Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: You're looking for CASE/WHEN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can take it from here..

```
select case when col like '%FirstHalf%' then 'FH'
            when col like '%SecondHalf%' then 'SH' else col end as col

from your_table;
```